# Make new environment conditionally

Tags: environments

I have created a custom LaTeX class for my personal use and encountered an issue when defining a new environment based on a certain condition. Here's a snippet from my class file:

```
\newif\if@sd\@sdtrue

\if@sd{
    \newenvironment{test}{Begin}{End}
}
\fi
```

However, when I tried to use this environment in another TeX file, I encountered the following error: "Environment 'test' undefined". I'm not sure why this error is occurring and how to resolve it.

Comment: remove the `{...}` if you make the `\newenvironment` in a group it is lost at the end of the group

Comment: Thanks! It works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `{...}` if you make the `\newenvironment` in a group it is lost at the end of the group